# Trying to use awk to print a column but says print not found

Tags: linux, bash, awk

So I am trying to do some homework and am having a lot of issues. This is the first script I have written in UNIX/Linux. Right now I am trying to print out a few columns from the free command and use awk to just grab those columns I need. Every time I try to do this, i get a bash: print command not found.

Command I am trying to use:

```
free | awk `{print $3}`
```

I have also tried without the {}.

So when It is finished I would like it to say for example: Total Free Memory: xx MB
with the xx filled in of course with the result.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:
Okay so don't use the backticks to get that to work. So now I would like the whole command to end up saying:
Total Free Memory: xx MB

The command I have so far is:

```
echo "Current Free Memory: " | free -m | awk '{print $3}'
```

I only want just that one column row intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for the field 4.
As I suggest using awk and sed but it is up to you.

Here is my suggestion :

```
freem="$(free -m | awk '{print $4}' | sed -n '2p')"

echo "Total Free Memory: $freem MB"
```

Where $4 is the columns you want  and 2p is the line you want.

Before writing the script, check your result in command line.

Comment: this is an extremely inefficient way to do things. piping awk to sed is unnecessary, since awk alone can handle it.

Comment: @fedorqui You are right but I gave him one of many other solutions possible. He can even use cut.... it always depend on your needs. Please feel free to share your suggestion

Comment: Just awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'

Answer (score 4):

You are saying

```
free | awk `{print $3}`
```

Whereas you need to say `awk '{...}'`. That is, use single quotes instead of backticks:

```
free | awk '{print $3}'
           ^          ^
```

Note this is explained in [`man awk`](http://ss64.com/bash/awk.html):

> Syntax
>
> ```
>   awk <options> 'Program' Input-File1 Input-File2 ...
>
>   awk -f PROGRAM-FILE <options> Input-File1 Input-File2 ...
> ```

Comment: Ahaa... Thank you. Our professor kept talking about using backticks and I guess I got confused.

Comment: So then how would I get just one line from the output. Like one column and row?

Comment: Better update your question showing what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Rather, post a new question, since asking how to print a specific row is not related to the backquote problem asked about in this question.

Comment: Okay I will post a new question after this one. I just updated it explaining the final part a little better I hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {print "Current Free Memory: " $4 " MB"}'
```